# Composition factor of a group which isomorphic to the alternating group of order 7

Tags: gr.group-theory

I want to find groups whose composition factor is isomorphic to the alternating group of order 7, which groups have this condiction?
best regards

Comment: Please read the FAQ, your question is out of place here.

Comment: Could you say why you want such a list of groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want some examples, one of the examples is the symmetric group $S_7$ of degree 7. Clearly, you can costruct infinite groups that one of the its composition factors is $A_7$. For example $S_7\times\Bbb Z_p^r$ where $p$ is a prime and $r\geq 0$.